# How to handle a null value from firestore when swift doesn't recognise this as nil?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am loading data from firestore and i check initially to see if the document exists. So if there is no document at all that is cool and i just return.

If there is a document there I thought I would setup guard statements for each field that is read in to determine if the field has data. But the guard statement really only determines if the field actually exists or not - if the field is set to Null then this still bypasses the guard.

So for example in my app a user will set a value and this is stored in firestore. But if for whatever reason the value isn't stored and is "Null" then i was wondering do I also need an if statement to check for null?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? What did you do to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by utilizing the `FieldValue.delete()` from `Firestore`.

Example:

```
func updateMyFirestoreDocument(value: String?) {
    Firestore.firestore()
        .collection("<my collection path>")
        .document("<my document id>")
        .setData(["value": value ?? FieldValue.delete()], merge: true, completion: { err in
            // You're completion handler
        })
}
```

Notice, in the case that the `value` is `nil`, I pass in `FieldValue.delete()` which has the effect of deleting the `value` field from the Firestore collection.